# HTML Form Select Dropdown Options and Hidden Form Fields Not showing in PHP Form using JS Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

Recently i set up a script in JS with help from Stack to show a Form Row labled "other" when i select  an option called "Other" from a dropdown option above. Example is below. This works well for one dropdown. But as soon as I add another dropdown Menu and "other" form row the JS code breaks and neither the 1st or 2nd Form Dropdown Options get posted to the Database and the form row "other" does not show. I hope i have explained the issue correctly. I essentially want one JS script to repeat for all dropdown forms so when "other" option value is selected i want the form row "other" to display below so custom data can be typed in. Using Bootstrap 4.3.1 with all JS querir plugins working. The datbase is connected with no issues posting data when its just a text field. So i was hoping someone might have work around and i will have a lot of dropdowns with the "Other" form row posting different form data in to the database. Many thanks.

```
    <script>
  function handleSelect() {
    document.getElementById("other").value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var details = document.getElementById("other-details");


    if (selected === "") {
      details.classList.remove("d-none");
      details.classList.add("d-block");
    } else {
      details.classList.remove("d-block");
      details.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Cemetery</label>
    <select name="cemetery" class="form-control" id="mySelect" onchange="handleSelect();">
      <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Cemetery</option>
      <option value="Akatarawa">Akatarawa</option>
      <option value="Taita">Taita</option>
      <option value="Wainuiomata">Wainuiomata</option>
      <option value="Whenua Tapu">Whenua Tapu</option>
      <option value="Makara">Makara</option>
      <option value="Karori">Karori</option>
      <option value="St Johns">St Johns</option>
      <option value="Awa Tapu">Awa Tapu</option>
      <option value="Paraparaumu">Paraparaumu</option>
      <option value="">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row d-none" id="other-details">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="cemetery" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Headstone - Stone Color</label>
    <select name="headstone_color" class="form-control" id="mySelect" onchange="handleSelect();">
      <option value="headstone_color" selected="selected">Select Headstone - Stone Color</option>
      <option value="Black">Black</option>
      <option value="African Grey">African Grey</option>
      <option value="Platinum Blue">Platinum Blue</option>
      <option value="Blue Pearl">Blue Pearl</option>
      <option value="Emerald Pearl">Emerald Pearl</option>
      <option value="White Pearl">White Pearl</option>
      <option value="Imperial Red">Imperial Red</option>
      <option value="Balmoral Red">Balmoral Red</option>
      <option value="G603-Chinese White/Grey">G603-Chinese White/Grey</option>
      <option value="">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row d-none" id="other-details">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
    <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="headstone_color" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the select id. both of the select has the same id as myselect. The id must be unique. So please make your code generic and use some unique ids.

Thanks

Something like this?

```
<script>
  function handleSelect() {
    document.getElementById("other1").value = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
    var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
    var details = document.getElementById("other-details1");

 document.getElementById("other2").value = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    var details = document.getElementById("other-details2");


    if (selected === "") {
      details.classList.remove("d-none");
      details.classList.add("d-block");
    } else {
      details.classList.remove("d-block");
      details.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  }
</script>
```

and so on ??